# Identify ARIMA Model from ACF & PACF plots

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I have plotted ACF & PACF plots for my data, but getting no significance on 1st lag and on further lags it is showing negative lag. please help to identify order of ARIMA model. Thank you[image]

Comment: There may be seasonality of length 12 in your series, based on the (tiny) ACF spike at lag 12. Are your data monthly? [Here is information on reading (P)ACF plots.](https://otexts.com/fpp2/seasonal-arima.html) That said, I would trust a modern model selection method based on information criteria, like `auto.arima()` from the `forecast` package in R, a lot more.

Comment: yes my data is monthly data from 2011-2020

Comment: sir when did seasonal differencing to my data, then also i was getting similiar ACF & PACF plots with 1st lag non significant and others being negative